# GDPR: How to stop smarty cache entries containing contact name being created?

Tags: cache

Under templates_c, a lot of .php files are being created that contain things like the following:

```
<?php /* Smarty version 2.6.30, created on 2018-04-27 00:20:41
         compiled from string:REDACTED */ ?>
<?php require_once(SMARTY_CORE_DIR . 'core.load_plugins.php');
smarty_core_load_plugins(array('plugins' => array(array('block', 'crmScope', 'string:REDACTED', 1, false),)), $this); ?>
<?php $this->_tag_stack[] = array('crmScope', array('extensionKey' => "")); $_block_repeat=true;smarty_block_crmScope($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], null, $this, $_block_repeat);while ($_block_repeat) { ob_start(); ?>string:REDACTED<?php $_block_content = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); $_block_repeat=false;echo smarty_block_crmScope($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat); }  array_pop($this->_tag_stack); ?>
<br/>
```

The problem is that the file names contain the names of contacts. Under GDPR, these need to be deleted.

Can we change the name to be the ID instead?

Comment: a) What part of GDPR implies this? b) You can delete everything under templates_c and it will be rebuilt as needed

Comment: Right to erasure. If someone requests that we delete all data we hold on them, for there to be a thing on our system, cached or otherwise, that contains their name, could be portrayed as not fully respecting that right.

Comment: Hi John - aren't these temporary files which are removed when you clear caches?

Comment: Yes. But I still don't see how more privacy is ever a bad thing. Also, I can imagine instances where these may be around longer than necessary: backups, clones, misconfigured server not being able to delete them, so on.

Comment: @JohnFF someone's name alone is not personal data within the scope of the GDPR if the information contained in a cached template is enough to identify the individual it would be within scope for GDPR and the Right to Erasure but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @JohnFF how would changing the name to the ID being different? Both could be traced back to a person.

Comment: Hi Jaap, 

Because you can redact / pseudonymise the name and then you aren't left with it elsewhere.